# Bootstrap Dropdown toggle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap dropdown toggle is not working when using it in responsive mode, so I have been using this code and tried each and every possible move to make sure it work but unfortunately I couldn't get what I wanted.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light px-2">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="company-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="company logo" height="20%" />
      <span class="company-name">Company Name</span>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav navbar-item">
        <a class="nav-link mx-3" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
        <a class="nav-link mx-3" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        <a class="nav-link mx-3" href="#">FEATURES</a>
        <a class="nav-link mx-3" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
        <a href="#" class=" nav-link login-btn mx-3">LOG IN</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask]. Also tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Your toggle button target doesn't match the collapse element ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have pass wrong id to collapseable content,refer to official documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/ for more info.For your case just make sure data-bs-target and div id are same.

```
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" ...>
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
```

and

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```